# How to parse JSON in Titanium SDk?

Tags: json, parsing, titanium-mobile, appcelerator-mobile

I have the following JSON object. How can i parse it?

```
{
   "0":{
      "productname":"2000 voltage va/1500 watt Step-up & Step-down Voltage Converter Transformer Vtr-2000va",
      "imageurl":"http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/41tZp8-FziL.SL160.jpg",
      "producturl":"http://www.searchupc.com/rd.aspx?u=d%2bKvXQ%2fFIfa95xJ38QYLyU4OUkBqBrcphyF%2fbVaEoj5T%2fjsx3y%2fHventbiluNMAD641XeGGqUyQ5JQ0kDwVY0%2fizy%2feMStjfhnK3vab2NMFLECe8bv1vKsseZwtqbneVrpk3UfzjwueUBm87YXCgYak%2bgrHyqvo8zlCVoZhSu8FvMqXgFIhrz7UbHz5rdGzFTNFoV4YN3DXToyQ8tcDYGAmk6MrTHcJf9qHJMPaI910Wk7%2bfli43M%2bTETLOuMsbMkQhZSycKalaEYDLq9koEWw%3d%3d",
      "price":"99.99",
      "currency":"usd",
      "saleprice":"",
      "storename":"amazon.com"
   },
   "1":{
      "productname":"Ostrich Hackle",
      "imageurl":"",
      "producturl":"http://www.searchupc.com/rd.aspx?u=d%2bKvXQ%2fFIfa95xJ38QYLyYHuiEfPQuvrTusBuKFMyxAtMCRVMoc9UZeJmNSSnDMX0lbsWZCKodvcbrTGEUGCO2BBlpJ7y5EyWTIyjXmdiSpaUj1khd2fbQrxgatQCUQQyzatk%2bNZdH7Hmd1voRFizEznxhQ53tkftuu6%2bbOehX5D7ef53P52MKyoehUPJ9cPhkqAvAkkuudtqELQJr3WBJU8pGFY1JdJIPu65N%2fWNII%2fMaDEOp720hJq31XFbkNm",
      "price":"1000.00",
      "currency":"usd",
      "saleprice":"",
      "storename":"amazon.com"
   },
   "2":{
      "productname":"Opi BURLESQUE Holiday 2010 ~Rising Star~ HLB09",
      "imageurl":"",
      "producturl":"http://www.searchupc.com/rd.aspx?u=d%2bKvXQ%2fFIfa95xJ38QYLySaervFME3ziZ2ark6tA1RYuwjdEgy8egf60DkN6uARuU%2bYGpR6B%2fbo%2fEFTtEBIoFpTKNrhJrktpuuqLRP9AMJk5O9X6uMoka1vJEKOGOXg0mJEExy5EFFGGODFRthR1xQzwrG43kKl0jU6mO4ZhjzO5W4kBnt9hLVEG78T9LhTm4CbO4nJ8sEAanke4Tn1k2eKOdDsjM0HXCEmQZnSbv%2bNLd24iPdXP1SFnoaFaQydi",
      "price":"5.90",
      "currency":"usd",
      "saleprice":"",
      "storename":"amazon.com"
   },
   "3":{
      "productname":"Meddiapers Absorbent Plus",
      "imageurl":"http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/51tQWKd5hML.SL160.jpg",
      "producturl":"http://www.searchupc.com/rd.aspx?u=d%2bKvXQ%2fFIfa95xJ38QYLyRQpi7yISXhgFqm980vqJMISJGki5N3Bda%2bVTv7soLtO9uO1BQAyHzMxioboGzlDVdi7IG3lGC8bTX3J58ZvsdIZZgJzJQ2WIXHuHu4fo%2bHNs4UISSDyh8ccYKSRgdQT1tkjwcBAsOTl5ecpBbH6Us9%2fJgwWSGtyOekBTNUaSmQbpAFX2vi6H1br9LPAd7ym7RY0pZcmYAQ21bC7%2bMfiAGA%3d",
      "price":"84.99",
      "currency":"usd",
      "saleprice":"",
      "storename":"amazon.com"
   },
   "4":{
      "productname":"Songs of Murder, Pain and Woe",
      "imageurl":"http://images.emusic.com/music/images/album/0/110/801/11080176/155x155.jpg",
      "producturl":"http://www.searchupc.com/rd.aspx?u=RNxK6UXSsPf3Ea72o8XklOleRz4EIMcFVo3oih5JwMu59TOerGE1WPGRu%2fxnElLipZ%2fyFjey7NayZB8f3Znj5UVqN6%2b%2bJyLrmoE7sv1rrNS%2bSvXPrhbOz18lJwRPYWNtvjzOMu6ciIZyHtMaXeA3%2fwgsViasrwxTSDKxP31RV46G0zpTX5p2FZuezGxY1yxBJ7htWSk%2bSs1T7QbBDdEv7dvln%2bxQUFrn2eIiH2nEn3dQUAyNAelEa4jeTQbhDPsO",
      "price":"0.0",
      "currency":"usd",
      "saleprice":"",
      "storename":"emusic.com"
   },
   "5":{
      "productname":"Opi Opi Burlesque Holiday 2010 Rising Star Hlb09",
      "imageurl":"",
      "producturl":"http://www.searchupc.com/rd.aspx?u=1obZMMCVp83xNDdKOrGPNkSnn1asTWEiBPxzjC3R7WKgF5yHc7Bncom2WXi5oIcIE%2f4ohYASydDXyi6Opl965KOjfT%2fp%2f2S4emtcBvMZH9nzHHMj9Pjjhe4ktpeUiY7DIcxxsbHyuJ9M2RZeSp82BshMrEZ8SGEZfdZNrdKU3qgmFR8wSt9sgXhM3I3UgGZW",
      "price":"8.5",
      "currency":"USD",
      "saleprice":"",
      "storename":"bpnails.amazonwebstore.com"
   }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use the JSON parser that comes with Titanium (assuming the above JSON is in a variable called jsonString):

```
var jsonObject = JSON.parse(jsonString);
var productName = jsonObject.0.productName;
```

To observe the information inside a JSON object, you use `JSON.stringify(jsonObject.0);`

As a separate, secondary point, why is your top level object in your JSON an object and not an array?

Comment: This is not working, can you tell how to remove the integer key!!

Comment: @MKAlatrash it is referring to the OP's JSON string, in that each element is an object inside the JSON object. To access each one, he has to access it via the object name, hence `jsonObject.0`. For usual circumstances, and what I suspect you are having issues with is your JSON is in an array, in which you would need to traverse your array and then access each element.